# Keys are stuck, not physically

Tags: windows-8

When I hold down my D key Windows acts if I'm still holding it when I'm not and I just want to play games without this issue. Safe mode doesn't have this issue.

Comment: "Keys are stuck, not physically" how do you know? Did you plug in a different keyboard? A stuck key is the MOST likely answer, regardless of what you are thinking.

Comment: Try a different keyboard if the keyboard is malfunctioning.

Comment: The sticky key problem doesn't happen in safe mode. I already said that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried plugging in a different keyboard and then trying to play or use the system. If the problem persists look for unusual processes using Task Manager(Ctrl+Shift+Esc) and kill them and then run a full system scan. Or another approach to the solution would be to update all the drivers related to input.

Comment: This problem doesn't exist in safe mode, so I don't think it's the keyboard's fault. I also accidentally ran an all driver test and everything was fine.

Comment: If you're wondering how I did it accidentally, I searched up how to enter safe mode, and Shift+F8 on boot does a full driver test, then I did another search, said hold shift and click restart, and made it into safe mode. Right now I'm doing a scan with malwarebytes (past 30 day trial, free) and I only found 1 PUP out of about 95,000 files. If anything new happens, I'll alert you.